# Sort one array the same way as another array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays:

```
[2, 4, -2, 4, 1, 3]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

and I want them to be sorted by the numerical array:

```
// output
[-2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4] // <-sorted by numerical order
["c", "e", "a", "f", "b", "d"] // sorted exactly the same order as the first array
```

while its actually not important if "b" or "d" comes first (they both have 4 in this example)

I found many questions about this online but none of them worked for me can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can arrays have a different length? How to process them then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) of the first array based on their value. This will return an array with indices of the array sorted based on the value of `numbers` array. Then use `map` to get the sorted values based on the indices

```js
const numbers = [2, 4, -2, 4, 1, 3],
      alphabets = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

const keys = Array.from(numbers.keys()).sort((a, b) => numbers[a] - numbers[b])

const sortedNumbers = keys.map(i => numbers[i]),
      sortedAlphabets = keys.map(i => alphabets[i])

console.log(
  sortedNumbers,
  sortedAlphabets
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A standard method is to take the indices of the key array for sorting and sort the indices as pattern for all other arrays by taking the index and the value from the key array.

At the end map the sorted arrays.

```js
var array1 = [2, 4, -2, 4, 1, 3],
    array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    indices = [...array1.keys()].sort((a, b) => array1[a] - array1[b]);

[array1, array2] = [array1, array2].map(a => indices.map(i => a[i]));

console.log(...array1);
console.log(...array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the entire thing in a Map. That way, you can independently sort the first array however you want and then use those values as keys to call respective value of second array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line by associating your two arrays and then ordering the items:

```
const x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]   
const y = [2, 4, -2, 4, 1, 3]

const result = y.map((val, index)=>({x:x[index], y:val})).sort((a,b)=>a.y-b.y).map(v=>v.x)

// -> ["c", "e", "a", "f", "b", "d"]
```